# How about using SVG(Scalable Vector Graphics) on desktop applications?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, svg

I am working in Train Traffic Controller software project.
My responsibility in this project is to develop the visual railroad GUI.
By now I am using some svg graphics in that GUI.

I prefer them because of their scalability talents.
Is it good or bad idea to use svg in a desktop application?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am assuming you are using the QSvgWidget ? http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qsvgwidget.html, nothing wrong with that

Comment: By now I am subclassing QGraphicsWidget and using QSvgRenderer in its paint method. I use this approach because I am using QGraphicsLinearLayout at same time.

Answer (score 1):

nothing wrong with it!

things like WPF are effectively the same thing, except a lot more optimized for UI.

I guess the tricky thing is hooking into the elements of the svg to give it extended functionality.